# golang regexp ReplaceAllStrings with backreference doesn't quite work

Tags: regex, go

Trying to capitalize each letter at begin of the word. I know that there is `strings.Title`, but that is too imprecise for my needs.

I am not sure why this does not work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\b([a-z])`)
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("my test string", strings.ToUpper("$1")))

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/C-8QG1FrOi

Comment: The go regexp package (and RE2) doesn't support backreferences.

Comment: @DaveC yes, it will make `John's book` as `John'S Book`, with regex, even at such limited support as in Go, you can avoid such behaviour, in this case just something like this will work `[^']\b([a-z])`.

Comment: @MikeKlemin -- edited it to "imprecise," which seems to be nearer the meaning you described -- hope that gets across what you were trying to say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ReplaceAllStringFunc`, example:

```
re.ReplaceAllStringFunc("my test string", func(s string) string {
                                          return strings.ToUpper(s)})
```

See working [demo](https://play.golang.org/p/Oil1S9-diy).

Your code doesn't work because:

```
re.ReplaceAllString("my test string", strings.ToUpper("$1"))
```

is the same as:

```
re.ReplaceAllString("my test string", "$1")
```

since the upper case of `$1` is still `$1`.